# How to solve this system of exponential equations?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, problem-solving

Solve the following system of equations ($x,y \in \Bbb R$):

$$\begin{cases} 
3^{x+3y-2} + 6\cdot 3^{y^2+4x-2} &=5^{5y-3x} + 2\cdot 3^{y^2-2y+1}\\
 1+2\sqrt{x+y-1} &=3\sqrt[3]{3y-2x}.
\end{cases}$$

I think about it but I still have no solution... :(

Since the second equation, I write $x+y \ge 1$ then $y \ge \dfrac{2}{3}x.$ So $y \ge \dfrac{2}{5}$.

I rewrite the 1st equation:
\begin{align*}
 3^{x+3y-2} + 6\cdot 3^{y^2+4x-2} &=5^{5y-3x} + 2\cdot 3^{y^2-2y+1}\\
\iff 3^{x+3y-2} + 6\cdot 3^{y^2+4x-2}& \le 5^{5y-3x} -3^{5y-3x}+3^{5y-3x} + 2\cdot 3^{y^2+2y+1}\\
\iff (3^{x+3y-2}-3^{5y-3x})(1+2\cdot 3^{y^2+3x-3y+1})& \le 5^{5y-3x} -3^{5y-3x}\\
\iff (9^{2x-y-1}-1)\underset{>0}{\underbrace{(1+2\cdot 3^{y^2+3x-3y+1}})}&\le \left (\dfrac{5}{3}  \right )^{5y-3x}-1.
\end{align*}
Now, I have trouble.... Can anyone post the roots of this system of exponential equations.

I really appreciate if some one can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Where is this monster coming from ? Are you sure about the $5$ in the top equation ?

Comment: Would a numerical solution suffice?

Comment: @  Yves Daoust: Yes, It's $5$. therefore, I still have no solution. Can you help me?

Comment: @ Rory Daulton: It's useful if you can post it.

Comment: where did this problem come from? it looks pretty interesting!!

Comment: It comes from my professor. Can you tell me this system of exponential equations has $x=?, y=?$

Comment: I guess that your professor tricked you. I see no easy way to handle those equations by hand. A graphical calculator able to deal with the implicit equations can help.

Comment: Can you post it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Post what ?????

Comment: Post your solution (you say the implicit equations)?

Comment: If $y=0$, since the 1st equation we have $x\approx 0.496155$ and the 2nd equation has no solution. :(

Answer (score 3):

The curves corresponding to the functions $y(x)$ , computed by numerical calculus, are drawn on the figure below.

Since they dosn't intersect, the system of equations has no real solution.

I guess that there is a mistake in the wording of the question or in copying the equations.

[image]

The more $x, y$ are large, the more the curves are distanced from one another :

[image]

Comment: I think so, I'll ask my professor again.

Comment: @ JJacquelin: Can you tell me what software used to draw the graph as above? Can you post software or link of software? Thank you very much.

Comment: @kimtahe6 : I used an home made software which was written with Borland-DELPHI. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delphi_(programming_language). Using it supposes to be familar with the Dephi progamming language.

Comment: Wow! You are very good. I learned program pascal but Delphi...It's the first time I have heard to it.

Comment: > the system of equations has no real solution. Is there a way to calculate complex solutions?